# Mongoose + Mongodb User.update not working

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

What I am trying to do is create a new collection, and push that collection into a specific User.collections array. I have read many stackoverflow posts and they all say to use either User.update() or User.findOneAndUpdate(). I am have no luck with either. I can create a Collection and that is saved to mongo so I know I am indeed accessing the db. Here is my code, if any of you can help I would appreciate it.

User Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const userSchema = new Schema({

    googleID: String,
    givenName: String,
    familyName: String,
    collections: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "collection"
        }
    ]
});

mongoose.model('users', userSchema);
```

Collection Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const collectionSchema = new Schema({
    type: String,
    name: String,
    gamesCollected: [
        {
            id: Number
        }
    ]
});

mongoose.model('collection', collectionSchema);
```

And my route:

```
router.get('/get_collection', (req, res) => {    
    const collection = new Collection({
        type: 'SNES',
        name: 'First SNES Collection',
        gamesCollected: [{ id: 5353 }]
    }).save();

    User.update({googleID: req.user.googleID}, {$push: {collections: collection}});
});
```

Answer (score 3):

[**Save**](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-save) is not a synchronous operation but asynchronous so you need to use the [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) it returns and handle it and once it is complete then update the user model. Something among these lines:

```
router.get('/get_collection', async (req, res) => {
    let collection = new Collection({
        type: 'SNES',
        name: 'First SNES Collection',
        gamesCollected: [{ id: 5353 }]
    })
    await collection.save().exec();
    await User.update(
     {googleID: req.user.googleID}, 
     {$push: {collections: collection._id}}
    ).exec();
});
```